# git is using https even with ssh urls

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've been working with github for GitHub time, using an SSH URL.
Today, github has decided to use https instead, and refuses to use SSH...

```
> git clone git@github.com:G******/app-****.git
Cloning into 'app-****'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

If I try to pull the changes from a repo, the result is the same:

```
> git pull origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I don't understand why and haven't find any help so far.
My `.git/config` file is configured to use SSH:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
    hooksPath = .githooks
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:G******/app-****.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[pull]
    rebase = true
[submodule "src/shared/rn-submodule-******"]
    active = true
    url = git@github.com:G******/rn-submodule-******.git
[submodule "src/shared/rn-submodule-button-****"]
    active = true
    url = git@github.com:G******/rn-submodule-button-****.git
```

I tried to generate a new ssh key and upload it on my GitHub account but it doesn't solve my issue.

Do you have any idea what is going on?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `git config --global --list | grep -Fi insteadof` Git can replace/rewrite URLs on the fly. See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf). Then perhaps you need to `git config --global --remove-section url.https://github.com.insteadOf`

Answer (score 2):

You have this

```
[url "https://github.com"]
    insteadOf = "git@github.com:"
```

in your `$HOME/.gitconfig`. This [replaces/rewrites](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) URLs on the fly. You need to remove the section from the config:

```
git config --global --remove-section url.https://github.com
```